# Adjust height when parent view layout is vertical in appcelerator ios

Tags: ios, layout, window, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have one window it's layout is vertical,i have added two child views for that window ,those views height will dynamically change.After adding the views to window,First view is not fit to it's contents  some gap is coming.Please help me  how to solve this.

below is my code

```
<Alloy>
  <NavigationWindow id="profBidPostNav" platform="ios">
    <Window id="profBidPostWin" layout="vertical">
        <View id="MainView" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"></View>
       <View id="customerServiceMainView" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" top="0%"></View>  
    </Window>
</NavigationWindow>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a screenshot to see the problem ?
I see two errors on your code, `hieght` instead of `height` and `top="0%"`. If your `Window` have vertical layout, no need to add `top` property.

```
<Window id="profBidPostWin" layout="vertical">
   <View id="MainView" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"></View>
   <View id="customerServiceMainView" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"></View>  
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for giving reply.Height is just spelling mistake when i post the question here, in my studio code height is fine.why i have kept top for the second view,because some gap is coming for that i have kept top is '' 0%''. i am getting the gap between the views.but i want exactly align the second view after the first view please help me.

Comment: Here  i am sharing the screen shot, i am getting the gap between views as a green color                                                                                                                                https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5M9lHypCjpzLWl1NXlKOVBVQ28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where have you defined that green? If it is the background color of the window then yes, there is some space between the two view, looking at that image I am more propensed to think that you are dynamically filling the two views, and that inside of one (probably MainView) there is this green block; little positioning tip, when you are looking to align two views, try to place the background color of them to really different color (eg, one red and one blue) so you can quickly understand where is the problem, when they are perfectly aligned remove this backgrounds.

Comment: yes that green color is the backgroundcolor of the window only.

Comment: Try to set bottom of MainView at 0 then, if you still see it there is something else between the two views.